# PHP and Curl not Returning Output with Variable

Tags: php, html, curl

Here is my index.php file...

```html
<?php

    // Defining the basic cURL function
    function curl($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // Setting cURL's URL option with the $url variable passed into the function
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // Setting cURL's option to return the webpage data
        $data = curl_exec($ch); // Executing the cURL request and assigning the returned data to the $data variable
        curl_close($ch);    // Closing cURL
        return $data;   // Returning the data from the function
    }
 $url1 = $_GET['link'];
    $response = curl($url1);
    $response = str_replace("./views","http://movietube.pm/views",$response);
 $response = str_replace("./lib","http://movietube.pm/lib",$response);
 $response = str_replace("./assets","http://movietube.pm/assets",$response);
 echo $response;
 ?>
```

```
// Defining the basic cURL function
function curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // Setting cURL's URL option with the $url variable passed into the function
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // Setting cURL's option to return the webpage data
    $data = curl_exec($ch); // Executing the cURL request and assigning the returned data to the $data variable
    curl_close($ch);    // Closing cURL
    return $data;   // Returning the data from the function
}
$url1 = $_GET['link'];
$response = curl($url1);
$response = str_replace("./views","http://movietube.pm/views",$response);
$response = str_replace("./lib","http://movietube.pm/lib",$response);
$response = str_replace("./assets","http://movietube.pm/assets",$response);
echo $response;
?>
```

Basically, what I want it to do is take an input
www.example.com?link=(link)
and return the HTML of the page, after executing the php...
On the output, it loads the page correctly, but it doesn't put in the tv show stuff, like the video player, the links, or the episode director...

What it does...

http://muchmovies.uphero.com/?link=http://www.tvstreaming.cc/watch.php?v=TGmi0OPy0Cc

What I want it to do...

http://www.tvstreaming.cc/watch.php?v=TGmi0OPy0Cc

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You have forgot to check for curl errors after curl_exec

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a problem with php variable $_GET['link'] because you put this link:

http://muchmovies.uphero.com/?link=http://www.tvstreaming.cc/watch.php?v=TGmi0OPy0Cc

And note that your query string will be this:
?link=http://www.tvstreaming.cc/watch.php?v=TGmi0OPy0Cc

This query string must be encoding and you are not encoding it, so, variable $_GET['link'] will not have the value that you need to do the curl.

I recommend you 2 options:

1. Encode url params
2. Or, pass the url using base64 encode then on your
   server use base decode

Please, tell me if this was the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought it might be a syntax error or something as well, but if you look at the bottom of the page, there are facebook comments, for that particular movie. I'm assuming that means the link is reaching the website and it is telling it to get that video. Unfortuently, the 3 parts that are missing are the most important to me, the video, the links to the video, and the episode guide.

Comment: Could it be a server-side thing that is blocking me from getting those html tags? in the debugger for the webpage, the entire video part is just gone.

Comment: No, the real problem is that the main content is loading using $.ajax POST requests, not only calling url that you think. Open firefox with firebug or Google Chrome with Chrome inspector, go to the url and see XHR requests, then you will know which url use.

Comment: Ok thank you. would this still be possible to do, with only PHP?

Comment: Yes, because with curl you can do all kind of request, POST at this case without any problem. But, if you want to scrap movies data I will recommed you use a public API like IMDB.

Comment: Cool, thanks man ill play with curl a bit more, i saw the requests and stuff. :)